# Arduino PID controller for Triac

Tags: potentiometer, analog-sampling, pid

I am designing a new soldering station which will use a 24 V ac soldering iron.

I started to make some research and I designed a few steps of the soldering station. I will use a 24Vac/100VA toroidal transformer. I will use a 24V/50W soldering iron with K type thermocouple. For the thermocouple I will use a LM358 amplifier. Please have a look at the attached schematic and code. The code is not ready yet and I need some help in making the connection between the PID library and output in the code.
The voltage on the soldering iron looks like: https://ibb.co/CMF1gQ0
If I rotate the pot, nothing happens on the screen of the scope.

https://ibb.co/vdDRmnJ

I wrote a few lines of code but I don't know how to make the connection between the PID library functions and the interruption function and the other variables in my code.

Please have a look at the code and at the schematic and tell me what you think...
I am waiting for your help.

```
#include <PID_v1.h>

int AC_LOAD = 1;    // Output to Opto Triac pin
double set_value = 0;
double input = 0;
double output = 0;

PID aaa_PID(&input, &output, &set_value, 1, 0.05, 0.25, DIRECT);

void setup()
{
  aaa_PID.SetOutputLimits(0, 128);
  aaa_PID.SetMode(AUTOMATIC);
  pinMode(AC_LOAD, OUTPUT);// Set AC Load pin as output
  attachInterrupt(0, zero_crosss_int, RISING);  // Choose the zero cross interrupt # from the table above
}

//the interrupt function must take no parameters and return nothing
void zero_crosss_int()  //function to be fired at the zero crossing to dim the light
{
  // Firing angle calculation : 1 full 50Hz wave =1/50=20ms 
  // Every zerocrossing thus: (50Hz)-> 10ms (1/2 Cycle) 
  // For 60Hz => 8.33ms (10.000/120)
  // 10ms=10000us
  // (10000us - 10us) / 128 = 75 (Approx) For 60Hz =>65
  int dimtime = (75*output);    // For 60Hz =>65    
  delayMicroseconds(dimtime);    // Wait till firing the TRIAC
  digitalWrite(AC_LOAD, HIGH);   // Fire the TRIAC
  delayMicroseconds(10);         // triac On propogation delay (for 60Hz use 8.33)
  digitalWrite(AC_LOAD, LOW);    // No longer trigger the TRIAC (the next zero crossing will swith it off) TRIAC
}

void loop()  {
  int set_point = analogRead(A1);
  set_point = map(set_point, 0, 1023, 150, 400);
  int in = analogRead(A0);
  input = map(in, 0, 550, 25, 400);
  set_value = set_point;
  aaa_PID.Compute();

}
```

Comment: Seems legit to me, though you might want to disable the interrupt while executing `myPID.Compute()`, since you can get garbled data in your interrupt, when it happens while the `Output` variable gets assigned. What exactly is your problem with the code?

Comment: the problem is that I don't know if I correctly wrote the zero_cross_int() function and I don't know where is the relationship between the output of the PID calculations and the output waveform of the Arduino. I meant in the zero_cross_int() function the read value should be the one from the zero crossing detector or the one from the potentiometer ?

Comment: It is not clear to me, what you mean. You changed your code again. Now you are reading a second analog input in the interrupt. Why? With your old code the logic was the following: analogread the potentiometer for the setpoint, calculate output of PID, use PID for driving the triac signal. Only missing was the reading of the input for the PID (since you are creating a soldering station, here you would have to measure the temperature) and assigning it to `Input`. The additional analogRead in the new code is meaningless (you don't use the value anywhere)

Comment: I modified the code again: A1 input is for the potentiometer and A0 is for the temperature sensor.

Comment: I have tried the code above and I am stuck at the potentiometer. I checked it in particular and it is working. But when I am rotating the knob, then nothing happens. I only see on the oscilloscope this waveforms: https://ibb.co/mBBnmk3

Answer (score 1):

> I need some help in making the connection between the PID library and
>   output in the code

PID calculates the value of `output` and it is used in `int dimtime = (75*output);`.

The `aaa_PID` object gets the reference to variable `output` with `&` so when the PID algorithm sets the output value it sets the value of this variable in your sketch.

`output` should be `volatile double output = 0;` because it is used in interrupt.

EDIT 2:

I hope you wired the zero crossing detector to pin 2, because that is the pin for external interrupt 0. And don't use pin 1 for Triac, it is wired to USB chip too.

EDIT:
Your code stays too long in interrupt. You exit the interrupt only in the time after firing the TRIAC and the next zero crossing.

In [this](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/63631/fan-regulator-control-from-arduino/63674?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C26.8685#63674) Arduino SE answer I offer two sketches which demonstrate Triac control. This is one of them:

```
#include <TimerOne.h>

const byte INTERRUPT_PIN = 2;
const byte TRIAC_PIN = 4;
const byte TRIAC_PULSE_MICROS = 30;

const int FADE_MAX = 9800;
const int FADE_MIN = 2000;

volatile bool triacOn;
volatile int period = FADE_MIN; // microseconds cut out from AC pulse

int fadeAmount = 10;

void zeroCrossing() {
  triacOn = false; // triac tuns off self at zero crossing
  Timer1.setPeriod(period); // to call triacPulse() after off period
}

void triacPulse() {
  if (triacOn) { // stop pulse
    digitalWrite(TRIAC_PIN, LOW);
    Timer1.stop();
  } else { // start pulse
    digitalWrite(TRIAC_PIN, HIGH);
    triacOn = true;
    Timer1.setPeriod(TRIAC_PULSE_MICROS);
  }
}

void setup() {
  pinMode(TRIAC_PIN, OUTPUT);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(INTERRUPT_PIN), zeroCrossing, RISING);
  Timer1.initialize();
  Timer1.attachInterrupt(triacPulse);
}

void loop() {
  period = period + fadeAmount;
  if (period <= FADE_MIN || period >= FADE_MAX) {
    fadeAmount = -fadeAmount;
  }
  delay(25);
}
```

the other uses direct registers access o AVR.

EDIT 3: mike's oscilloscope output of the sketch above: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dnfy_EsPlVI

EDIT 4: the PID outputs high values for high power and small values for lower power. but the Triac period is the off time. so the period should be something like `period = 11000 - (75 * output)`

here are the input and output values of mike's code based on this answer (blue is temperature, red is output for the Triac period):

[image]

The PID control gets smoother over time as it finetunes its parameters,
but I think a simple PID has some problems with the sine relation between the output (time) and the resulting heating power.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107366/discussion-on-answer-by-juraj-arduino-pid-controller-for-triac).

Answer (score 1):

I see several issues here.

The most serious is in the wiring of the Arduino. The first argument of
`attachInterrupt()` is an interrupt number. On the Uno, “interrupt 0” is
wired to the pin “digital 2”. This is where you should connect the
output of the zero-crossing detector (ZERO_OUT).

Then, as noticed by Juraj, there is the issue of the interrupt handler
taking too long to execute. This is generally considered bad practice,
and it has some negative consequences on the working of the Arduino core
like, e.g., the `millis()` function will be completely off. I do not
think, however, that this is a serious issue for you. There is one
single time-critical bit in your program, which is the generation of the
triac trigger pulses. You really do not care about `millis()` or any
other time-related things. Thus, at least for the initial version of the
program, I would not care too much, and just let the interrupt handler
delay as needed.

The third issue has been noted by chrisl in a comment: there is a race
condition with both the main program and the interrupt handler accessing
the same `output` variable. Race conditions are a nasty kind of bug
because usually things work fine “most of the time” and then fail at
unexpected times. I would not recommend, however, to run
`myPID.Compute()` with interrupts disabled: that may throw off the
timing of your triac pulses. Instead, compute the delay required by the
interrupt, save it to a temporary variable, then copy it to a variable
shared with the handler. Only the copy needs to be done with interrupts
disabled, and that takes only a handful of CPU cycles:

```cpp
// Variable used by zero_crosss_int().
// Do not forget the `volatile' qualifier.
volatile int dimtime;

void loop() {
    // PID and associated computations.
    set_value = map(analogRead(A1), 0, 1023, 150, 400);
    input = map(analogRead(A0), 0, 550, 25, 400);
    aaa_PID.Compute();
    int tmp_dim_time = 75*output;

    // Critical section executed with interrupts disabled.
    noInterrupts();
    dimtime = tmp_dim_time;
    interrupts();
}
```

---

**Edit**: If things do not work, you should try to debug piece by piece.
Sending debug messages to the serial port should help, although serial
communication is likely to be significantly slowed down by the
long-running interrupt handler. As an alternative, you can use the triac
control pulses as a debug aid, maybe with the heating element unplugged.
For example:

- In `loop()`, set `dimtime` to a value proportional to `set_value`.
  Turn the pot and look at the FIRING_PULSE signal. Does the pulse
  width vary proportionally to the pot position? Is it in sync with the
  V<sub>in</sub> zero-crossings?
- Set `dimtime` proportional to `input`. Heat the thermocouple by some
  external means. Does FIRING_PULSE vary as expected?
- Set `dimtime` proportional to `output`, but keep the heating element
  unplugged. How does the pulse change as you move the pot or heat the
  thermocouple?

Comment: I added the code into my program and I run it, but on the scope screen appears something like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rAK9ounINAQ , and the heating of the soldering iron does not stop. As the temperature increases, the voltage on the soldering iron heater also increases...

Comment: @mike_mike: did you fix the wiring?

Comment: Yes, the “interrupt 0” is wired to the pin “digital 2”, as you said.

Comment: @mike_mike: Are you sure the PID parameters are sensible for your system? How did you tune them?

Comment: The PID parameters are from another soldering station, which used a mosfet instead of a triac.