# ESP32 + Attiny85 AC Dimmer

Tags: i2c, esp32, avr, attiny85

I am working on an AC Dimmer project using ESP32 and Attiny85.

> Note : I know ATtiny85 is overkill for this project, And it can be done without Attiny85, I have already done this using ESP32 alone. But I have some PCB laying around designed in such a manner. So thought of doing this.

Here ESP32 communicates to Attiny over i2c.
ESP - Master
Attiny - Slave
[image]
Here Zero Cross Detector(ZCD) circuit is connected to PB1. and T1 to Triac Circuit

Depending on the commands over i2c from ESP to each Attiny, It controls the brightness.

**The Problem**

I am able to set the brightness using i2c (like LOW, MED, HIGH, OFF). But only once.
For example, if I set it to HIGH state initially it will get stuck in that state, Even if any other command is given, Similar for all others. Basically, it will only work once.

I think the interrupt is causing the problem, once interrupt is attached the i2c isn't responding

Here are codes 
**Slave**           https://pastebin.com/sqsMYLa0

```
#include "PinChangeInterrupt.h"
#include "TinyWireS.h"
 
#define I2C_SLAVE_ADDR  2
int AC_LOAD = 3;
int ZCD_Pin = 1;
int dimming = 128;    
int Speed[3] = {90, 50, 20};
int speedValue;
bool fan;


void setup() {
  pinMode(AC_LOAD, OUTPUT);       
  TinyWireS.begin(I2C_SLAVE_ADDR);
  TinyWireS.onReceive(receiveEvent);
  pinMode(ZCD_Pin, INPUT_PULLUP);
}
 
 
void zero_crosss_int()  //function to be fired at the zero crossing to dim the light
{
  int dimtime = (75 * dimming);  // For 60Hz =>65
  delayMicroseconds(dimtime);    // Wait till firing the TRIAC
  digitalWrite(AC_LOAD, HIGH);   // Fire the TRIAC
  delayMicroseconds(100);         // triac On propogation delay  // (for 60Hz use 8.33) Some Triacs need a longer period
  digitalWrite(AC_LOAD, LOW);    // No longer trigger the TRIAC (the next zero crossing will swith it off) TRIAC
}
 
void receiveEvent(uint8_t howMany)
{
  byte byteRcvd = 0;
  if (TinyWireS.available()) {
    byteRcvd = TinyWireS.receive();     // get the byte from master
 
    if (byteRcvd == '0') {
      fan = false;
      detachPinChangeInterrupt(digitalPinToPCINT(ZCD_Pin));
      digitalWrite(AC_LOAD, LOW);
    }
    if (byteRcvd == '1') {
      fan = true;
      speedValue = Speed[0];
      attachPCINT(digitalPinToPCINT(ZCD_Pin), zero_crosss_int, RISING);
    }
    if (byteRcvd == '2') {
      fan = true;
      speedValue = Speed[1];   
      attachPCINT(digitalPinToPCINT(ZCD_Pin), zero_crosss_int, RISING);
    }
    if (byteRcvd == '3') {
      fan = true;
      speedValue = Speed[2];
      attachPCINT(digitalPinToPCINT(ZCD_Pin), zero_crosss_int, RISING);
    }
    dimming = speedValue;
  }
}
 
void loop() {
  delay(100);
}
```

**Master**        https://pastebin.com/E5U74LEx

```
#include <Wire.h>
//#define I2C_SLAVE_1_ADDR  1
#define I2C_SLAVE_2_ADDR  2
 
void setup() {
  Wire.begin(); // join i2c bus (address optional for master)
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.print("Ready");
}
 
char x = 0;
 
void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
 
    x = Serial.read();
 
    if (x == '0') {
      Wire.beginTransmission(2); 
      Wire.write('0');              
      Wire.endTransmission();    
      Serial.print("Send 0");
    }
    if (x == '1') {
      Wire.beginTransmission(2); 
      Wire.write('1');           
      Wire.endTransmission();   
      Serial.print("Send 1");
    }
    if (x == '2') {
      Wire.beginTransmission(2); 
      Wire.write('2');              
      Wire.endTransmission();    
      Serial.print("Send 2");
    }
    if (x == '3') {
      Wire.beginTransmission(2); 
      Wire.write('3');              
      Wire.endTransmission();  
      Serial.print("Send 3");
    }
  }
}
```

For testing, I have used Serial monitor for sending commands. Later It will be done using MQTT

Comment: That's a pretty long delay in the ISR; have you tried setting a state and handling the rest in `loop`?

Comment: @DaveNewton Yes, but the output is flickering. 
 here is the code https://pastebin.com/FnTkE8hZ

Comment: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/63631/fan-regulator-control-from-arduino/63674#63674